# How to solve $|1+1/x| > 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I am having a problem with this question:

> Find all real $x$ that satisfies $|1 + 1/x| > 2$.

This is clearly not defined in $x = 0$.
By my logic, it should be solved with:

> $1+1/x > 2$   or  $1+1/x < -2$

But the result I am getting from this is wrong. ($x<1$)

Correct result is

> $-1/3 < x < 1$

How to solve a problem like this? Why is this logic not working here:

> $|x| > 2$
>
> $x > 2$ or $x < -2$

Comment: You say you are getting the wrong answer, but you don’t say what you did, so we cannot tell you where you went wrong. We can only show you how to do it right; while that has value, you should want to know also where you went wrong and why.

Comment: This is the part I don't understand - I guess I should not get rid of the fraction: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3497935/how-to-solve-11-x-2?noredirect=1#comment7193485_3497943

Comment: When you multiply an inequality, you have to be *very* careful with whether you are mutliplying by a positive or negative number. This is particularly important when you multiply by an expression involving the unknown... since you may not know if it is positive or negative. In that case, you can figure out the unknown must be negative, so your calculation is **incorrect** (since you did not switch the inequality sign).

Comment: In general, if you have two expressions in the unknown, say $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, and you are trying to solve $f(x)/g(x)\lt 0$, then you need to solve the system $f(x)\gt 0$ and $g(x)\lt 0$ (numerator positive and denominator negative, so fraction is negative); and the system $f(x)\lt 0$ and $g(x)\gt 0$ (numerator negative and denominator positive so the quotient is negative). Similarly when you want to solve $f(x)/g(x)\gt 0$ and cannot figure out the sign of either $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ from other considerations. That’s your error.

Comment: Please [**use MathJax**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your subsequent questions on Math SE. You can click on "Edit" to see how I have edited your post to use MathJax.

Comment: I can see how you got $x < 1$ from $1 + \frac 1x > 2$ but I don't see why you didn't attempt to get anything from $1+\frac 1x < -2$.  That should have given you $x > -\frac 13$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you failed "switch" signs for negative values.

Either $1 + \frac 1x < -2$ or $1 + \frac 1x > 2$.

If $1 +\frac 1x <-2$ then $\frac 1x < -3$ and $x$ is negative.

So $1 > -3x$ (inequality flipped because $x < 0$)

$-\frac 13 < x$ (ditto for $-3$).  And as $x$ is negative.

$-\frac 13 < x < 0$

***OR***

$1 +\frac 1x > 2$ so $\frac 1x > 1$ and $x$ is positive and $x < 1$.  So $0 < x < 1$.

So $-\frac 13 < x < 0$ or $0 < x  <1$ or $x \in (-\frac 13,0) \cup (0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot - my problem was that I didn't know when x is positive or negative. How did you know that here: 1/x < -3 is negative? Did you write graph for this?

Comment: Sorry, I see it  now - in this case 1/x < -3 it's not possible for x to be positive. Thanks again for your answer and your effort.

Answer (score 3):

Taking from $$|1+\frac1x|>2\implies 1+\frac1x>2\ \text{or}\ 1+\frac1x<-2,$$  this gives us two cases:

Case 1:  \begin{align} 1+\frac1x&>2\\ \frac1x-1&>0\\
\frac{1-x}x&>0\implies 0<x<1
\end{align}

Case 2:  \begin{align} 1+\frac1x&<-2\\ 3+\frac1x&<0\\
\frac{3x+1}{x}&<0\implies-\frac13<x<0
\end{align}

We can then take the union of the two sets, and the final answer is $\boxed{-\dfrac13<x<1, x\neq0}$.  Your mistake probably comes from solving the rational inequality incorrectly.

---

Edit:  here is how I would solve rational inequalities, in general.

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{3x+1}{x}$.  The zeroes of the numerator and denominator are $-\dfrac13$ and $0$.  Use these to form bounds of intervals.

\begin{array}{|r|c|c|c|}
\hline & 3x+1 & x & \text{sign of } f(x) \\
\hline
x<-\frac13 & - & - & +\\
-\frac13<x<0 & + & - & -\\
x>0 & + & + & + \\
\hline
\end{array}

Since we want $f(x)=\dfrac{3x+1}{x}<0$, it follows that the solution is $-\dfrac13<x<0$ from the table above.

Comment: This part is not clear to me: (3x+1)/x < 0. If multiply with x: 3x+1 < 0, so x < -1/3. It seems like in this case: (3x+1)/x < 0 it is prohibited to multiply with x? Is this the rule if zero is on the other side of equation?

Comment: This step only assumes that $x \ne 0$. But when $x = 0$, $|1+\frac{1}{x}|$ is undefined so this step is valid.

Comment: @FrenkyB: If the quotient is negative, then $x$ cannot be positive (if it were positive, then both $3x+1$ and $x$ are positive, so the fraction is positive). So when you multiply by $x$, you *need* to switch the inequality sign, so you get $3x+1\gt 0$ instead of $3x+1\lt 0$.

Comment: @FrenkyB: So you get $x\gt-1/3$. Then, since you *also* know $x\lt 0$, you get $-\frac{1}{3}\lt x\lt 0$.

Comment: In general, I advise against "multiplying through" when solving inequalities.  Rather, simply know that the product of an odd number of negative factors is negative, and the product of an even number of negative factors is positive.  I will explain with an edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you square both sides, you obtain $$\left(1+1/x\right)^2>2^2,$$ or $$(1+1/x)^2-2^2>0,$$ which factors as $$(1+1/x-2)(1+1/x+2)>0,$$ or $$(1/x-1)(1/x+3)>0.$$ This implies $1/x<-3$ or $1/x>1.$ This implies $0>x>-1/3$ or $0<x<1.$ Hence the solution is the set of all $x\ne 0$ in $(-1/3,1).$

Comment: Can you please show step by step from here: (1/x−1)(1/x+3)>0. My thinking is that either both are positive or both are negative - how did you made your calculation from here on?

Comment: @FrenkyB Examine the signs of the factors in each of the intervals $(-\infty,-3),(-3,1),(1,+\infty).$ Or, since this is just quadratic, imagine its graph.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$1+\frac1x > 2 \iff \frac1x > 1 \iff 0 < x < 1$$

and similarly

$$1+\frac1x < -2 \iff \frac1x < -3 \iff -\frac13 < x < 0$$

Therefore we have

$$\left|1+\frac1x\right| > 2 \iff 1+\frac1x > 2 \text{ or } 1+\frac1x < -2  \iff -\frac13 < x < 0 \text{ or } 0 < x < 1$$
which is equivalent to $$x \in \left\langle -\frac13, 1\right\rangle\setminus \{0\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's follow your logic and see where it leads us. Start with the first case

$$1 + \frac{1}{x} > 2.$$

This means that $\frac{1}{x} > 2 - 1 = 1 \implies 0 < x < 1.$ Note that you got $x < 1,$ which is not true, because if $x < 0,$ we clearly have that $\frac{1}{x} < 0 < 1.$

On the other hand, your second case has

$$1 + \frac{1}{x} < -2.$$

In this case, $\frac{1}{x} < -2 - 1 = -3.$ Note that in this case, $x$ *must* be negative. Solving the inequality as such, we have that $0 > x > -\frac{1}{3}.$

We take the union of these two cases for the complete solution set: $-\frac{1}{3} < x < 1, x \ne 0.$

Answer (score 1):

$x\not =0$;

1) $1+1/x >2$;

2) $1+1/x <-2$;

1) $1/x >1$;

Then $x >0$:

$1>x$, i.e $0<x<1.$

2) $1/x < -3$;

Then $x<0$:

$1>-3x$ ; $-1/3 <x$ ; i.e $-1/3<x<0$;

3) Altogether: $x \in (-1/3,0)\cup (0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
|1+1/x|>2&\iff 1+1/x>2 \text{ or } (1+1/x)<-2\\
&\iff 0<x<1 \text{ or } -\frac13<x<0.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, $x\ne 0$ and:
$$|x+1|>2|x| \iff (x+1)^2>(2x)^2 \iff (x-1)(3x+1)<0 \iff -1/3<x<1$$
Hence:
$$x\in (-1/3,0)\cup (0,1)$$

Comment: I didn't know that you can multiply with |x|. Perhaps you have some link where these rules are written?

Comment: How come from this (-x+1)(3x+1)>0 to this (x−1)(3x+1)<0 ?

Comment: @FrenkyB If `ab` is positive, `-ab` is negative. In this case, `-(-x+1)` is `x-1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you divide it by .2 or .5 or basically values < 1 you get higher values:

1 + (1 / .2) = 6

1 + (1 / .5) = 3

I'm not a mathematician so this may be missing the point of your equation, but this does make it true I believe since the order of operation is division before addition

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).